# Website within Skyrim

Tags: modding, web, html, skyrim-modding

I'm new to the Skyrim Creation kit but I've been through a few tutorials and looked through the documentation but I couldn't see a way to do this. Is it possible to display an HTML page within the game itself? Like a popup screen in-game that displays Google or other site? I've looked for a couple of days but feel I might be chasing something that's not possible.

Thanks

Comment: I *highly* doubt it, what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe we can help with that.

Comment: Hi Kevin - I would like to create a mod where, whilst you're in game, you're able to search the web in the corner of the screen to help out with your quest (e.g. what to do/where to go etc...)

Comment: Yeah that's not likely to be possible. Also shift-tab for steam?

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case, I was hoping for a WebView control of some sort in there. Shift-tab works, I just wanted to mess around with modding too. Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this same problem. When I saw that books in the creation kit are created in html coding, I decided to experiment by adding a `<a href=`. When I opened the game, the entire hyperlink text was not displayed. As far as I'm concerned, the only way to do what you wanted would be to open the in-game steam browser, but I don't think that there would be a way to make it appear without the player pressing shift-tab.

Answer: No. It is highly unlikely that you would be able to browse the internet from within Skyrim, with or without mods.